# How to register Action<object> & Predicate<object> in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, icommand

I'm creating an a WPF app that has a button with the `ICommand` binding.
Anyway, I've decided to add DI using Castle Windsor. The main problem is that I don't have any idea about how to register types `Action<object>` and `Predicacte<object>`. My code is:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
```

etc.

To satisfy `RelayCommand`, CW should be able to resolve those. Any ideas?

UP: errors informations are as follow:

```
'App.WPFClient.RelayCommand' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'System.Action`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' which was not registered.
- Service 'System.Predicate`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' which was not registered.
```

Comment: Action<T> is just a delegate that takes an input of type T and its return type is "void", a Predicate<T> is a delegate that takes an input of type T with a return type "bool". So you're really just passing methods that match those delegates.

Comment: I suggest you read on Delegates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/

Comment: @Sven, thanks for your advices. I'm on it!

Comment: So, I've come up with this: container.Register(Component.For<Func<object>>().Instance(() => )) but I'm not sure what's the body of expression...